# MYsql Load balancing using opsworks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks, galera

I have been working with mariaDB and galera cluster.   i would like to set this up to be load balanced.   i am using AWS currently.  no i can not use RDS for the solution i am looking for.
    Can anyone help me out using opsworks and HAproxy to create a load balanced galera cluster?  or is there an easier way of doing this?

Thanks

For some guide information we have an application in a Elastic Beanstalk setup. that can grow as needed.
Currently there is a master slave setup for the database but i am switching to a galera cluster. for sake of example we can call them Galera-1 Galera-2 and Galera-3

Thank you for any advice.